# Free online calling service

Tags: web-services, href

does anyone know of an online calling service which I can use on my website. My website has a list of companies with toll free 1800 numbers and I want to make the numbers callable when clicked by linking them to a free calling service. Is there any service that does this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create a hyperlink as shown here, which will prompt the user to choose a program like skype or whatever, just as your computer will ask you whether to use MS Word or Notepad when download a text file.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/?hl=en

Edit: just to be clear Skype allows for free 1800 calls https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA24/how-do-i-dial-toll-free-numbers-for-example-1-800-1-866-and-1-877-number-series

Comment: I know that Skype offers this, but what if the user doesn't have Skype?

Comment: They could still use Google voice, WeChat, or Facetime Audio, or if they are on mobile, the default phonecall app. If they don't have any of these when they click the link they wont be able to make a call, and have to type  it into their phone like a barbarian.